# Spyder and Python Debug: can not set breakpoint

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I am not able to add breakpoints in my spyder IDE with Python3.6

I have tried restarting my computer, but neither with `F12`nor by clicking on `Debug -> Set/Clear breakpoint` let's me enter a breakpoint. Could anybody explain what I am doing wrong? I am sure this is a stupid error.

I am running Spyder 3.1.2 on a Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to set new breakpoints after starting a debugging session in an IPython console, that was fixed in Spyder **3.1.3**. So please update to that version.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much!!

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as an aswer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set new breakpoints after starting a debugging session in an IPython console, that was fixed in Spyder **3.1.3**. So please update to that version.

Answer (score -1):

Running ipdb in Spyder 3.6.2 on Win 10.  When I hit continue, the debugger bypasses all breakpoints.  Doesn't matter whether I set them inside the debugger or prior to in the editor.  Breakpoints do not work in Spyder 3.6.2 on Win 10

Comment: There's no 3.6.2 version of Spyder, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, Dyslexic, Spyder 3.2.6 o n Win 10.  Breakpoints still don't work.  Set Breakpoint on a line with double click in editor.  From menu, select Debug.  Stopes at first executable line as it should.  Select ctrl-F12 Continue, ipdb breezes right past the breakpoint.  Code uses Qt QFileDialog to select a file.  One thing, Spyder throws:

Comment: Ok, that version is very old (two years and a half, I think). Please update to our latest one (4.1.5, if you're using Anaconda; 4.2.0, otherwise) and try again.

Comment: Updated to Spyder 4.1.5, breakpoint still did not work.  However, in examination of the detail error I found the trace terminated in a TimeoutError exception thrown from spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\comms\kernelcomm.py.  "Timeo."ut while waiting for comm port"  That led me to the .spyder-py3\config\spyder.ini file which I restored to the original.  Problem solved.  This must have been a side effect of a remote debug session I tried to set-up for a Linux cross-build.  Suggestion to people with this problem - check your spyder.ini file.